# Display shopping cart data in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making a shopping cart app in xamarin.android and got success in retreiving data from rest API.I cannot figure out what is the best way to dynamically display that data.There are lots of options since i m new i m confuse which one to use .Hope You guys will help me.

Comment: provide issue, not entire one

Comment: issue is i cannot figure out best approach of displaying my json data.like i should use lists or recycler views or card views etc.

Comment: there is no "best" - it depends on your requirements and preferences.  Look at how other similar apps do it.  Or just pick an approach and try it - if it doesn't work, then try something else.  We can't make your decision for you.

Comment: as i mentioned i m developing a shopping cart and i asked for suggestions not to choose for me .I thought this platform is where experienced help fresh ones that's why asked.

Comment: Please read "How to Ask" in the Help section.  There are multiple guidelines this question violates - it's too broad, it solicits opinions, etc

Comment: You might want to review how the shopping cart works in the reference app, `eShopOnContainers`,  https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers